# About IIS APPPOOL

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I have to debug a WCF hosted in local IIS. Each time I have to attach two processes "w3wp.exe".

One ID is 7624, the other is 8372.

Users: one is "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated[administrator]

```
   the other one is "IIS APOOL DefaultAppPool[administrator]
```

Questions:

1. What they are? (google search but bo clue)
2. Can I just attach one process rather all?

Thanks

**Updated:**
See IIS image:
[image: iis pool]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application pool is the set of apps that run under same worker process.

Important thing in practice is that one app pool can serve only applications with same version of .NET (version of .NET CLR - to be precise). It is also good to remember that applications from the same app pool will "share" recycling of worker process.

So, you should look up at the IIS in which app pool your service is running and debug only process associated with this app pool.

Comment: click on each app pool and select "view applications" from actions menu until you find out which pool runs your app -- then you will have answer which process you should debug

Answer (score 1):

Just check in your IIS Management Console the Application Pool in which your site resides, then attach to the proper one. Probably, as you're using WCF, you're running under .NET 4, so under the first process you linked.

Answer (score 0):

They are Application Pool Identities. This is the newer (and securer) way of assigning priveleges to websites. Essentially a site runs on its own application pool, so you assign rights to files based on that pool.

See: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Do I have to attach two processes or just one?